# Display all errors except of selected ones in blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

When I want to display all errors in blade after validation I use this piece of code.

```
@foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
     <li>{{ $error }}</li>
@endforeach
```

But what if I want to display all errors except of a few selected. I.e. I want to dismiss all errors coming from input named `email` (`$error->has('email')`). Is it possible to do it in laravel in a smart way?

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the solution. `$errors` is a type of MessageBag and I used methods from collections.

```
@php
    $errors = collect($errors->getMessages())->except(['email']);
@endphp
@foreach ($errors->flatten()->all() as $error)
    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the `$errors` is a Laravel collection. Read more about Collections [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections)

We can try [except()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-except)`:

```
$erros= $errors->except(['email']);
```

Now

```
$errors->all()
```

would return the new collection without `email`.

Happy coding.

Comment: Thank you for response, but `$errors` is not laravel collection, but `MessageBag`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can access the errorBag with the following code.

```
if ($errors->getBag('default')->has('email'))
```

I think you can also get the error keys in your foreach

```
@foreach($errors->all() as $key => $error)
    @if($key === 'email')
        @continue
    @endif
    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
@endforeach
```